# How to use the points which come from the leaflet file layer plugin?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, html, jquery

I am using leaflet file layer plugin.I have added a kml file which includes some points. I want to do sth by using these points. But I don't know if the plugin saves this data or not. How can I use these points?

https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.FileLayer/issues/24

In the link you can see what I mentioned.